# Can I add a Quick export to PDF button on my view form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, export, pdf

is there a way to export my view to PDF? so I can paste it into visio?

Comment: why are you pasting it to Visio? The closest thing you can do is export the list to Excel, unless you want to write something in code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use 'Snipping Tool' (Search in your Start Menu), select whatever you need to copy and paste it into Visio (Not really a SharePoint question).